# Apply discount/coupon ONLY for backordered products

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, coupon, discount

I'm trying to add a discount code just for backordered items, I found this one on here and it works for ALL items, not just backordered items, how can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'specific_coupons_valid_for_backorders', 10, 3 );

function specific_coupons_valid_for_backorders( $is_valid, $coupon, $discount ){

    // HERE below define in the array your coupon codes
    $coupon_codes = array( 'beauty' );

    if( in_array( $coupon->get_code(), $coupon_codes ) ) {
        $is_valid = false;

        // Loop through cart items and check for backordered items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if( $cart_item['data']->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                $is_valid = true; // Backorder found, coupon is valid
                break; // Stop and exit from the loop
            }
        }
    }
    return $is_valid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WC_Discounts` class sets the cart items, so looping through the cart items within the function isn't going to work. There's another filter `woocommerce_coupon_get_items_to_validate` that you can use to set the items. As an easier solution you could use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63424561/6670570) and apply the discount as zero if the item isn't on backorder.

```
    function filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount( $discount, $price_to_discount , $cart_item, $single, $coupon ) {    
    // On backorder
    if ( !$cart_item['data']->is_on_backorder() ) {
        $discount = 0;
    }
        return $discount;
    }
    
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Thanks @Matts it worked perfectly!